# How to fix this water damage to ceiling?

Tags: repair, drywall, ceiling, water-damage

Please see the picture, what's the best strategy to fix this? The skin which is quite thick is peeling off but the back end is quote solid. I have stopped further water leakage.

Should I be cutting the dry wall piece and put another one or I can manage fixing it without that?

[image]
[image]

Should I rip of the nearest crown molding as well and put it back?

Or this project better left to a professional?

Comment: i would cut out a hole the size of the new drywall panel by tracing it. then you can just pop it in and re-mud.

Comment: I would remove the molding, and cut to the wall. Expose the area, ensure its clean, then repair along the seams, toe in 2x4 as needed to ensure a tight fit

Comment: Is that drywall? And the gypsum is discolored from the water?  I would remove the trim as noybman suggests , 2 seams that will be hidden+ @noybman you should work that into an answer

Comment: I was reluctant to make it an answer because I wasn't confident it was drywall, (does it contain asbestos maybe?) I was hoping someone else would pipe up. I mean, it DOES look more like drywall than anything else, but the super thick paint+paper layer gave me pause. Maybe the damage and discoloration is from sewer water